# Nondecreasingness of $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}$ implies the nondecreasingness of $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^{1+\varepsilon}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

Let $\Phi:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ be a convex function, i.e. $\Phi(\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2)\leq \lambda\Phi(t_1)+(1-\lambda)\Phi(t_2)$ for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $t_1,t_2\in[0,\infty)$. Let also $\Phi(0)=0$. Therefore, $t\in(0,\infty)\mapsto\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}$ is a nondecreasing function. Indeed, $t_1=\frac{t_1}{t_2}t_2+\big(1-\frac{t_1}{t_2}\big)0$, then
$$
t_1\le t_2\Rightarrow\Phi(t_1)\leq\dfrac{t_1}{t_2}\Phi(t_2).
$$
My question is can we say that "nondecreasingness of $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}$ implies the nondecreasingness of $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^{1+\varepsilon}}$ for some $\varepsilon>0$."

Comment: No. Take $\Phi(t)=(t+1)\log(t+1)$ for example.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Thanks for your comment. I see $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}$ is a nondecreasing function for $\Phi(t)=(t+1)\log(t+1)$. But i can't show why $\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^{1+\varepsilon}}$ is not nondecreasing for $\Phi(t)=(t+1)\log(t+1)$. Can you write more explictly?

Comment: If you know something about $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log(x)/x=0$, it would be easier to check via $\Phi(1)>0$ while $\lim\Phi(t)/t^{1+\varepsilon}=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Here's a very simple example, in fact a bit trivial. Let $$\Phi(t)=t.$$ This is (non-strictly) convex on $[0,\infty)$ and $\Phi(0)=0$. The function $$\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}=1$$ is nondecreasing in $(0,\infty)$, but $$\frac{\Phi(t)}{t^{1+\epsilon}}=t^{-\epsilon}$$ is not, because it is a negative power.